# iTextSharp pdf add custom header on every page

Tags: c#, header, itext, document, pdf-writer

I am iterating a list and it is creating new page automatically, I want to add table header on every new page

[Image with header on first page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjKXM.png)

[I want same header on second page second page created while list iteration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLoqj.png)

I try to add html string

Comment: Which iText version do you use?